# Export selected content models and their content to another space in Contentful

Tags: json, command-line, contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I have two content space **QATesting** and **Development**. I've created 3 new content models and contents in Development. The names of new models and their content type ids are `User Care Tips (userCareTips)`, `User FAQ (userFAQ)` and `User Demo (userDemo)`. I have also added few entries to them and it has images and video assets as well. Now I'm trying to move just these 3 models and their content to my space **QATesting**

I have checked up on the tutorial link [here](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/cli/import-and-export/) and installed contentful. Now trying to export and import. Below is the `example.json` file that I created for export

```
{

  "spaceId": "Development Space Id",
  "managementToken": "Development access token",
  "contentTypes": ["userCareTips","userFAQ", "userDemo"],
  "entries": [],
  "assets": [],
  "locales": [],
  "webhooks": [],
  "roles": [],
  "editorInterfaces": []
}
```

When I run the below command to export I'm getting error.

> Unknown arguments: contentTypes, entries, assets, locales, webhooks,
>   roles, editorInterfaces

```
contentful space export --config example.json
```

I'm new to contentful, can someone guide me how do I achieve this.

Comment: Hi Sonu,
The contentful space export command has this flag that may help you:
```
--query-entries           Exports only entries that matches these queries
                                                                         [array]
```

Comment: How does `--query-entries` work?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I am also trying to get a specific content model but without any luck

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the below config file to export the specific Content.

{
"spaceId"   :"******",
"environmentId": "master",
"contentOnly": true,
"queryEntries": [
"content_type=#######", // Content Model ID
"sys.id=########" // Content ID
]
}

after that u can hit below command to export

contentful space export --config env_conf.json